"Failed to resolve module specifier 'events'." when bundling node modules with esbuild and esbuild-deno-loader [DENO 2]
I'm building a Chrome extension, using Deno to manage my node_modules, and esbuild-deno-loader to bundle the modules into a local file, since Chrome extensions do not allow external dependencies.
The bundle command runs without error, but when I view the extension in browser, the graph.bundle.js script isn't properly rendering/injecting the html that it's supposed to.
I get
this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "events". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". 
I was successfully able to run the script in browser when I used node.js and webpack bundler instead of deno.js and esbuild, so the problem definitely resides there, I just don't know how to fix it.
(LLM couldn't help me either)
The module that's failing to resolve is "events", which my direct dependencies in turn depend on.
Why is esbuild failing to bundle "events" properly but webpack is succeeding?
graph.js >> file getting bundled
// Graph generator function from graphMLGEN.js
import { generateMapGraph } from './graphMLgen.js'

// Sigma and Graphology libraries
import { Sigma } from 'sigma';
import { Graph } from 'graphology';
import random from 'graphology-layout/random';
import ForceSupervisor from 'graphology-layout-force/worker';
import graphml from 'graphology-graphml';

// Load the graph structure from the graphMLGEN.js file
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function() {
    const windows = await chrome.windows.getAll({ "populate": true });
    const xml = generateMapGraph(windows);

    const graph = graphml.parse(Graph, xml);

    random.assign(graph)
    const layout = new ForceSupervisor(graph, {maxIterations: 5});
    layout.start();

    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    const sigmaInstance = new Sigma(graph, container);
});

bundle.js config file.
// JS Bundling Tools
import * as esbuild from "npm:esbuild";
import { denoPlugins  } from "jsr:@luca/esbuild-deno-loader";

const result = await esbuild.build({
    plugins: [...denoPlugins()],
    entryPoints: ["./src/sigma/graph.js"],
    outfile: "./dist/graph.bundle.js",
    bundle: true,
    format: "esm",
    platform: "browser",
    target:"es2023",
    sourcemap:true,
    treeShaking:true,
});

esbuild.stop();

deno.json
{
  "tasks": {
    "dev": "deno run --watch src/deno/main.ts",
    "run": "deno run src/deno/main.ts",
    "bundle": "deno run --allow-run --allow-env --allow-read --allow-write --allow-net bundle.js"
  },
  "imports": {
    "sigma": "npm:sigma",
    "graphology": "npm:graphology",
    "graphology-layout/random": "npm:graphology-layout/random",
    "graphology-layout-force/worker": "npm:graphology-layout-force/worker",
    "graphology-graphml": "npm:graphology-graphml",
    "xmlbuilder2": "npm:xmlbuilder2",
    "pretty-data": "npm:pretty-data"
  }
}


Sounds like esbuild didn't find events in your source code's dependencies automatically. Try finding where it is used and why esbuild missed it. Then either change how it's used and loaded or describe it explicitly as an external dependency in your esbuild config.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre]? The node:events module is a built-in module that cannot be bundled (by esbuild, webpack, or any other bundler) — it is made available by the Node.js runtime and is not available in the Google Chrome runtime.
